# jQuery-ui MultiDatesPicker plugin - jumps many years ahead when trying to select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I've been struggling with using the MultiDatesPicker plugin for jQuery ui. I have it so there are only a few dates eligible to be chosen, and any time I try to click on one of those dates, it jumps forward to January 2020.

I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox and gotten the same result.

I have made a jsfiddle that illustrates what is happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/krrj7v45/

These are the settings that I have set for the MultiDatesPicker:

```
$('.datepicker').multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        addDisabledDates:disabled,
        minDate:dates[0],
        maxDate:dates[dates.length -1],
        inline: true,
        numberOfMonths: months,
        changeMonth: false, 
        changeYear: false
    });
```

I've read other documented problems about the year jumping around, but none of the workarounds prescribed have fixed the problem at all.

EDIT: I figured out the problem: It is because the minDate and maxDate properties only take an input that is related to the current day, not an absolute date. Eg, you would put mindate: +1 if you wanted to always have the calendar show dates starting at whatever date tomorrow is. I wrote a script on the server side to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="datepicker">
```

Must be `<input class="datepicker" />`

http://jsfiddle.net/krrj7v45/1/